# creating xml element with two namespaces using libxml APIs

Tags: libxml2

I want to create an xml element having two namespace as below:

```
element name="Root" xmlns:xsi="myXSI" xmlns:xsd="myXSD"
```

I have checked out with the existing APIs, but it is not getting in this form. I am getting as

```
Root xmlns:xsd:xsi="myXSI" xmlns:xmlns:xsd="myXSD"
```

I am using this APIss as below:

```
xmlTextWriterWriteAttributeNS(xmlWriter, BAD_CAST "xmlns:xsd", BAD_CAST "xsi" , BAD_CAST "myXSD", BAD_CAST "myXSI");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
xmlTextWriterWriteAttributeNS(xmlWriter, BAD_CAST "xmlns", BAD_CAST "xsi", NULL, BAD_CAST "myXSI");

xmlTextWriterWriteAttributeNS(xmlWriter, BAD_CAST "xmlns", BAD_CAST "xsd", NULL, BAD_CAST "myXSD");
```